# AWS Amplify Cors issues

Tags: aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I have a dead simple app on amplify and have been dealing with this cors issue far too long. I hope someone here can help...

I have a call from my browser (client side) html page to my server, using fetch. Should be super simple, but not on AWS! So cors issue and I try to follow the directions for using the API Gateway and and all that and it keeps wanting me to do it with a lambda. I have a form that sends an address to the server via using a route in express (`/api`) which I'm calling with fetch. Here, a little code might explain better!

Here's the call made from my HTML doc...

```
    const address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        const url = `/api?address=${encodeURIComponent(address)}`; 
          fetch(url)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
              const divisionIds = data.offices.map(
                (office) => office.divisionId
              );
```

which in turn calls the `/api` route in my JS file:

```
app.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('API endpoint was called') // Added line for debugging
    
    const address = req.query.address;
    const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key=API_KEY&address=${encodeURIComponent(address)}`;
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);

        console.log('Response status:', response.status, response.statusText);
        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            res.json(data);
        } else {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during fetch:', error);
        res.status(500).send(error);
    }
});
```

My query, is do I really need to do all the silly AWS code for one simple call? I feel a Lambda function might be too much. Is there a possible way around the cors issue? I've tried headers, plugins, etc and no simple fetch call will work. Any guidance with this would be greatly appreciated!